# Dynamic dataset url in Apache Superset with Apache Drill

Tags: apache-superset, apache-drill

I connect Apache Superset with apache Drill via sqlalchemy-drill.
Here is connection:

```
"type": "http",
"cacheResults": true,
"connections": {
  "get": {
  "url": "http://localhost:5500/",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": null,
  "authType": "none",
  "userName": null,
  "password": null,
  "postBody": null,
  "params": null,
  "dataPath": null,
  "requireTail": true,
  "inputType": "json",
  "xmlDataLevel": 1
  }
},
"timeout": 5,
"proxyType": "direct",
"enabled": true
```

In Superset I getting the data:

```
SELECT * FROM api.get.`link`
```

But in api I need to get the data via dynamic urls like "link/1", "link/2" etc.
I'm trying to use Jinja template for inserting urla parameter into query:

SELECT * FROM api.get.`{{ url_param('url') }}`

And then in the dashbord use url like "http://localhost:8088/superset/dashboard/1/?url=link/1" for accessing to parameter? but it doesn't work.

Is there any way to use dynamic url for access to api from Superset?

Answer (score 1):

Need to set ENABLE_TEMPLATE_PROCESSING in superset_config.py to TRUE and all works